# Simple Network chat in Java

Tags: java, networking, tcp, client

just had a question to a simple chat program i wrote in java.
The program uses TCP to transmit simple message strings back and forth from Server/Client. And it works on all the computers on my Network. But when i sent it to a friend of mine to see if it worked from his computer it did not. So my question is: Would i need to add some specific code to allow messages from other comps from outside my network to be recieved? or is it some kind of Firewall that is preventing this?

Comment: Where is your server? outside or inside your network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a firewall or a router.

Firewall: port is not opened.

Router: message are not forwarded to the machine which hosts your application.

Or your application is using the internal IP and not the IP from the internet (which has to be forwarded to your internal ip)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :)no, the computer that runs the server application is not behind the router, but yes the ip used to receive messages from the client program(my friend) is the internal ip this computer. So just to clairfy, what do i do from here?

Comment: Not so easy...
If you want to be able to chat with him, you can use the external IPs and route the port to your respective machines...
But, this will not work anymore between your machine...

Other solution, which works everywhere.. you start a tcp listener on each client.. the clients send the ports, on which they are listening, to the server... you route the **different ports** to your different machines... or you only pull the message from the server, checking if it is for this user/machine... and push message to the user to the server...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify anything special in the code for computers that's not on the internal network, then it won't handle them differently. It won't handle the connections differently by itself. I'd check your(or his) router and open any ports that you use.